# Draw a truncated rectangular pyramid

Tags: matlab, drawing

How can I draw a truncated rectangular pyramid in Matlab ?
Base and top rectangles should have 4:3 aspect ratio.
[image]
Image is shown as guideline. The ability to look through it like a funnel would be nice.

```
>> x = [0 0 0 0; 1 1 -1 1; 1 -1 -1 -1];
y = [0 0 0 0; 5 5 5 5; 5 5 5 5]; 
z = [0 0 0 0; 1 1 -1 -1; -1 1 1 -1];
fill3(x,y,z, ones(3,4))
```

This achieves a pyramid 
[image]

Now all I need is some adjustments to cut the peak.

Comment: Try to find the intersections. That should be straight forward I guess. The sides can then be plotted with `patch`. If you show your efforts to solve the problem first, you may get better help with the rest. Good luck!

Comment: thanks , I now have a starting point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x =[ 3/4 -3/4 -3/4 -3/4; 3/4 3/4 -3/4  3/4; 3 3 -3  3;  3 -3 -3 -3];
y =[ 5/2  5/2  5/2  5/2; 5/2 5/2  5/2  5/2; 5 5  5  5;  5  5  5  5]; 
z =[-4/2  4/2  4/2 -4/2; 4/2 4/2 -4/2 -4/2; 4 4 -4 -4; -4  4  4 -4];
fill3(x,y,z, ones(4,4)) 
grid
```

This will create truncated square pyramid with 4:3 aspect ratio at the base.

[image]